# Solving subset sum problem on superincreasing list using a Self Organizing Map (SOM)

Tags: encryption, cryptography, combinatorics, self-organizing-maps

I have read quite a few articles that discuss the applications of SOMs to solving the traveling salesman problem, but haven't seen SOMs applied to many other combinatorial optimization problems. I am looking to implement the Merkle-Hellman encryption scheme, and would like to try my hand at using an SOM to solve the subset sum problem that is a part of the algorithm. Has this been tried before? Any suggestions/tips on how I should get started with this?

I am currently in the research phase of this process, so I've mainly been looking around at different papers and articles that discuss the applications of SOMs to combinatorial optimization problems. I've also been reading up on the Merkle-Hellman scheme quite a bit to familiarize myself with the algorithm/process.